# Create exchange mailbox in c#

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server-2013

I want to create Mailbox in exchange server 2013 using c# .

I tried lots of codes but each one gets an error that there is no obvious solution to solve it.

my code is

```
public static Boolean CreateUser(string FirstName, string LastName, string Alias,string PassWord, string DomainName, string OrganizationalUnit)
    {
        string Name = FirstName + " " + LastName;
        string PrincipalName = FirstName + "." + LastName + "@" + DomainName;

        Boolean success = false;
        string consolePath = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\exshell.psc1";
        PSConsoleLoadException pSConsoleLoadException = null;
        RunspaceConfiguration rsConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create(consolePath, out pSConsoleLoadException);
        SecureString spassword = new SecureString();
        spassword.Clear();

        foreach (char c in PassWord)
        {
            spassword.AppendChar(c);
        }

        PSSnapInException snapInException = null;
        Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig);
        myRunSpace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeLine = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline();

        Command myCommand = new Command("New-MailBox");
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("Name", Name);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("Alias", Alias);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("UserPrincipalName", PrincipalName);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("Confirm", true);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("SamAccountName", Alias);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("FirstName", FirstName);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("LastName", LastName);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("Password", spassword);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("ResetPasswordOnNextLogon", false);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("OrganizationalUnit", OrganizationalUnit);
        pipeLine.Commands.Add(myCommand);
        pipeLine.Invoke();     // got an error here
        myRunSpace.Dispose();
       }
```

and call it :

```
Boolean Success = CreateUser("firstname", "lastName", "aliasName", "AAaa12345", "mydomain.com", "mydomain.com/Users");
```

which I get this error :

```
Additional information: The term 'New-MailBox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

and another code that I test is:

```
string userName = "administrator";
        string password = "mypass";
        System.Security.SecureString securePassword = new System.Security.SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password)
        {
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }
        PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(userName, securePassword);
        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("https://{my server IP}/POWERSHELL/Microsoft.Exchange"),
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange",
        credential);

        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
        connectionInfo.SkipCACheck = true;
        connectionInfo.SkipCNCheck = true;
        connectionInfo.MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 2;

        using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
        {
            runspace.Open();
            using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                powershell.Runspace = runspace;
                //Create the command and add a parameter
                powershell.AddCommand("Get-Mailbox");
                powershell.AddParameter("RecipientTypeDetails", "UserMailbox");
                //Invoke the command and store the results in a PSObject collection
                Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
                //Iterate through the results and write the DisplayName and PrimarySMTP
                //address for each mailbox
                foreach (PSObject result in results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        string.Format("Name: { 0}, PrimarySmtpAddress: { 1}",

                result.Properties["DisplayName"].Value.ToString(),
                result.Properties["PrimarySmtpAddress"].Value.ToString()

                ));

                }
            }
        }
```

and I get this error

```
Additional information: Connecting to remote server {Server IP Address} failed with the following error message : [ClientAccessServer=WIN-FRP2TC5SKRG,BackEndServer=,RequestId=460bc5fe-f809-4454-8472-ada97eacb9fb,TimeStamp=4/6/2016 6:23:28 AM] Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

I think I gave every permission which is needed to my administrator user and firewall is off  but it doesn't work yet.

Any help or hint !!
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unchecked "prefer 32-bit" and changed platform target to x64, the problem was solved.

with the following code :

```
 public class ExchangeShellExecuter
{

    public Collection<PSObject> ExecuteCommand(Command command)
    {
        RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConf = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        PSSnapInException PSException = null;
        PSSnapInInfo info = runspaceConf.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010", out PSException);
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConf);
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.Add(command);
        Collection<PSObject> result = pipeline.Invoke();
        return result ;
    }
}
    public class ExchangeShellCommand
{
    public Command NewMailBox(string userLogonName,string firstName,string lastName,string password
        ,string displayName,string organizationUnit = "mydomain.com/Users", 
        string database = "Mailbox Database 1338667540", bool resetPasswordOnNextLogon = false)
    {
        try
        {
            SecureString securePwd = ExchangeShellHelper.StringToSecureString(password);
            Command command = new Command("New-Mailbox");
            var name = firstName + " " + lastName;

            command.Parameters.Add("FirstName", firstName);
            command.Parameters.Add("LastName", lastName);
            command.Parameters.Add("Name", name);

            command.Parameters.Add("Alias", userLogonName);
            command.Parameters.Add("database", database);
            command.Parameters.Add("Password", securePwd);
            command.Parameters.Add("DisplayName", displayName);
            command.Parameters.Add("UserPrincipalName", userLogonName+ "@mydomain.com");
            command.Parameters.Add("OrganizationalUnit", organizationUnit);
            //command.Parameters.Add("ResetPasswordOnNextLogon", resetPasswordOnNextLogon);

            return command;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    public Command AddEmail(string email, string newEmail)
    {
        try
        {
            Command command = new Command("Set-mailbox");
            command.Parameters.Add("Identity", email);
            command.Parameters.Add("EmailAddresses", newEmail);
            command.Parameters.Add("EmailAddressPolicyEnabled", false);

            return command;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        //
    }

    public Command SetDefaultEmail(string userEmail, string emailToSetAsDefault)
    {
        try
        {
            Command command = new Command("Set-mailbox");
            command.Parameters.Add("Identity", userEmail);
            command.Parameters.Add("PrimarySmtpAddress", emailToSetAsDefault);

            return command;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        //PrimarySmtpAddress
    }


}
```

and run with :

```
 var addEmailCommand = new ExchangeShellCommand().AddEmail("unos4@mydomain.com","unos.bm65@yahoo.com");
        var res2 = new ExchangeShellExecuter().ExecuteCommand(addEmailCommand);

        var emailDefaultCommand = new ExchangeShellCommand().AddSetDefaultEmail("unos4@mydomain.com", "unos.bm65@yahoo.com");
        var res3 = new ExchangeShellExecuter().ExecuteCommand(emailDefaultCommand);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Secure String

string pwd = "Password";
char[] cpwd = pwd.ToCharArray();
SecureString ss = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in cpwd)
ss.AppendChar(c);

//URI

Uri connectTo = new Uri("http://exchserver.domain.local/PowerShell");
string schemaURI = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange";

//PS Credentials

PSCredential credential = new PSCredential("Domain\\administrator", ss);

WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(connectTo, schemaURI, credential);
connectionInfo.MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 5;
connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
Runspace remoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
remoteRunspace.Open();

PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = remoteRunspace;

ps.Commands.AddCommand("Get-Mailbox");
ps.Commands.AddParameter("Identity","user@domain.local");

foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke()) 
{
Console.WriteLine("{0,-25}{1}", result.Members["DisplayName"].Value,
result.Members["PrimarySMTPAddress"].Value);
}
```

Comment: .... is not configured for the target.If Kerberos is not required, specify the Negotiate authentication mechanism and resubmit the operation. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

Comment: is your exchange server inside your AD, or outside of it? if it's outside use Basic Authentication

Comment: i get this error : Additional information: Connecting to remote server mydomain.com failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: The computer mydomain.com is unknown to Kerberos. Verify that the computer exists on the network, that the name provided is spelled correctly, and that the Kerberos configuration for accessing the computer is correct. The most common Kerberos configuration issue is that an SPN with the format HTTP/mydomain.com