# Create mailbox on exchange 2010 using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, exchange-server-2010

I am trying to create a user mailbox on Exchange 2010 through my C# windows app.
Here is my code

```
        PSCredential creds = new PSCredential("user id", StringToSecureString("password"));
        System.Uri uri = new Uri("http://servername/powershell?serializationLevel=Full");

        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

        PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
        PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
        command.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
        command.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
        command.AddParameter("ConnectionUri", uri);
        command.AddParameter("Credential", creds);
        command.AddParameter("Authentication", "Default");
        powershell.Commands = command;
        runspace.Open();
        powershell.Runspace = runspace;
        Collection<PSSession> result = powershell.Invoke<PSSession>();

        powershell = PowerShell.Create();
        command = new PSCommand();
        command.AddCommand("Set-Variable");
        command.AddParameter("Name", "ra");
        command.AddParameter("Value", result[0]);
        powershell.Commands = command;
        powershell.Runspace = runspace;
        powershell.Invoke();

        powershell = PowerShell.Create();
        command = new PSCommand();
        command.AddScript("Import-PSSession -Session $ra");
        powershell.Commands = command;
        powershell.Runspace = runspace;
        powershell.Invoke();

        powershell = PowerShell.Create();
        command.AddCommand("Invoke-Command");
        command.AddParameter("ScriptBlock", System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create("New-Mailbox"));
        command.AddParameter("Name", "FnameLname");
        command.AddParameter("Password", "abcd@123");
        command.AddParameter("Alias", "FLname");
        command.AddParameter("OrganizationalUnit", "Company/OU");
        command.AddParameter("UserPrincipalName", "Fname.Lname@Domain.com");
        command.AddParameter("SamAccountName", "FLname");
        command.AddParameter("FirstName", "Fname");
        command.AddParameter("Initials", "FL");
        command.AddParameter("LastName", "Lname");
        command.AddParameter("Database", "dbname");
        command.AddParameter("LinkedMasterAccount", @"company\FLname");
        command.AddParameter("LinkedDomainController", "domain controller");
        powershell.Commands = command;
        powershell.Runspace = runspace;
        var createmailbox = powershell.Invoke();
```

But I get the below error when I execute the above code.

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Name'

Comment: is there any other details to the error message?

Comment: No. That's the only exception message I receive

Comment: Have you tried Display, DisplayName or GivenName

Comment: Yes.Same error. What happens is this error comes for all parameters. If I remove "Name" then it will show the error for next parameter "Password" and so on

Comment: I dont know C# well enough but I think you are not adding parameters to `New-Mailbox` but instead to `Invoke-Command` which does not have name etc.

Comment: I had same doubt so I removed all parameters and modified my code.   `command.AddParameter("ScriptBlock", System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create("New-Mailbox -Name Fname"));` This will return 0 count when invoked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create exchange mailbox in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449219/create-exchange-mailbox-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @James- I get error that Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010 is not installed on this machine (my local machine). Is it necessary to execute mailbox commands  remoterly through .Net?

Comment: @Member0927 to use Exchange PowerShell commands you need the Exchange PSSnapin installed on your local computer (this comes within the Exchange Management Tools). The other option is to establish a PSSession to a computer that has them.

Comment: @James- I've established PSSession to remote server where Exchange Server is installed. I've updated my code in question. If I remove "Invoke-Command" and replace it with "New-Mailbox" then it throws error that "New-Mailbox is not recognized as valid cmdlet"

Comment: Yes you need to connect to Exchange before any commands are available `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1"; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto`

Comment: Sorry James but I didn't get you. What changes I need to make in my code?